In a .NET design, how to combine services (dependency injection) and object with constructors?
We are redesigning an ASP.NET MVC application that has business logic in helpers. We want it to have DI services (passed to controllers by dependency injection).
We have 2 concepts that we don't understand how to handle with DI services:

We want a way to 'construct' the service with mandatory properties, like we do in the helpers. Example is shown below.
Business logic might use DI services internally, but it looks ugly to pass all DI services, used anywhere in internal classes, from within the controllers, where they are available only.

Example missing constructor
We could have a mail service that inits in Startup.cs with basic config like SMTP server, SMTP port, etc. It doesn't set the From: user, because in the application the From: user is different, so it needs to be passed as a parameter, like
_mailService.Send(from, to, subject, message)

But what if we do something like this in the helpers now?
MailHelper mailhelper = new MailHelper(from, to);
mailhelper.Send(subject1, message1);
mailhelper.Send(subject2, message2);
mailhelper.Send(subject3, message3);

How do you do this in DI? I suspect you could do:
_mailService.NewBatch(from, to);
_mailService.Send(subject1, message1);
_mailService.Send(subject2, message2);
_mailService.Send(subject3, message3);

What I don't understand
Please help me understand:

What if one forgets to call _mailService.NewBatch(from, to) in the example above, do you need to keep track of that in the service yourself? You could throw an exception if someone is using Send() without calling NewBatch() first, but with the helper and constructors you couldn't forget. And since these services have a long lifespan, they can still hold the old from and to.

If you have a combination of helpers and DI-Services. Do you pass all DI-services as parameters in the constructor of the helpers? Even for service that are required by logic deep inside the helper (like for logging)?



To help with #1 your service should not be "holding on" to a "new batch" that has be to maintained as state for a caller (unless you want to get into some kind of session state). If its a singleton service, write it so it works for your controllers no matter who calls it or when they call it. Otherwise, don't make it a long-lived service. In particular if its a singleton service, consider that it might be used by more than one caller at the same time.

#2 - not sure you have explained this well enough to answer. Simply asking about what to do with "helpers" is too vague. "Helpers", "Services", "Managers" are not well defined terms. You need to be more specific. We don't know what you mean by "a combination of helpers and DI-Services".

Thank you. About #2. In a classic OOP model, the Mail-object might initialize a SMTP object, that could initialize an IP-object, and so on. The 'user' in the MVC controller wouldn't know. If you change it to a mailservice, with DI, what if the mailservice requires another service itself (internally)? Like a smtpservice. That would not be available within the mailservice, is it? Would you need to pass it from the MVC controller as a parameter? Like _mailService.Send(from, to, subject, message, _smtpservice, _ipservice, ....etc)

I try to avoid a lot of interdependencies in my services so I don't get where they all depend on each other. That said, at my last job my coworkers didn't care so much and all our services basically all did depend on each other. We never ran into any real problems (not an extremely complex project) - so your mailservice could have its own injection of smtpservice and ipservice (but don't overdo it). Also hey what's wrong with helpers? Seems you are just converting a service called a helper to a service called a service. DI doesnt necessarily need to change your code that much.

The first option described,
_mailService.Send(from, to, subject, message)

is easiest in this context, because it clearly demarcates run-time values from services. My recommendation is to design APIs like that.
If, for legacy reasons, you can't do that, then write a Decoraptor with such an API, and use that. You can implement the Decoraptor on the API that doesn't quite work for you, like the MailHelper example.
If that, for some reason I can't imagine, isn't possible, define an Abstract Factory that creates an IMailHelper object from from and to.
I can't think of a single good reason to define an API like the NewBatch suggestion. It has exactly the problems outlined in the OP, and no mitigating qualities.

Thanks. I will have a look at the Decoraptor pattern. I agree that my example is a bit simple, but we have logic that requires to be 'setup' with an effect-date, current user, logfile, etc. It would be elegant to do that just once per 'short lifespan' (like in an old constructor).
